# N+1 detected on parent of parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

Here are my model associations:

```
Expense belongs_to Supplier belongs_to Concept

# For example:
"ADSL Connection and Telephone July 2" > Comcast > Internet
"Water Bill August 20" > PG&E > Water
```

I'm trying to list all of my expenses, and also show both the company it's paid to, and what concept they belong to.

The `bullet` gem is alerting me to an N+1 query and recommend I include it:

```
N+1 Query detected
  Supplier => [:payment_concept]
  Add to your finder: :include => [:payment_concept]
```

And in my controller, I already included the Supplier (for another N+1) issue, but when I try to include the `:payment_concept` I get an error that it's not a recognized symbol:

```
@expenses = Expense.all(:include => [:supplier, :payment_concept])

# In my view:
.rows
  - for expense in @expenses
    .item
      p.date.lato= expense.date_made
      p.supplier.lato= expense.supplier.name
      p.payment_concept.lato= expense.supplier.payment_concept.name
      p.payment_type.lato= expense.payment_type.name
      p.account.lato= expense.account
      p.price.lato= number_to_currency(expense.price)
      .item-actions
        = link_to '<i class="icon-remove"></i>'.html_safe, '#', class: 'small-button'
```

Understandable given that Expense only has a relationship with the supplier, and not directly with it's concept.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```
 @expenses = Expense.all(:include => [:supplier => :payment_concept])
```

Edit:

For clarification, since `Concept` belongs to `Supplier` (which belongs to `Expenses`), you need use a hash relationship in the `includes` statement.